# ADC specs: fpbw - infinite resistor noise?

Tags: adc

I'm trying to compute Johnson resistance noise in a simple resistor circuit. However, since all frequencies contribute equally, I am getting an answer of infinity.

It then dawned upon me that the Arduino ADC probably detect frequencies larger than some cut off given by something called the full power bandwidth. Does anyone know this spec for the Due?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the full power bandwidth spec you are looking for but is related to the settling time of the sample and hold.

Page 244 of the ATmega328 data sheet (assuming you have a 328) shows that the input of the ADC can be represented by the source resistance together with internal sampling switch resistance (1..100K) and the 14pF sampling cap.  This will give a single pole filter that will limit the bandwidth and avoid all frequencies up to infinity contributing to the total noise.

Comment: I'm using the Due, which has a SAMX8E processor (data sheet here: http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-11057-32-bit-Cortex-M3-Microcontroller-SAM3X-SAM3A_Datasheet.pdf) - do you know what the cut-off would come out to in that setting?

Comment: @Dave might be a good idea to learn how to identify and read the datasheet so you know. "Give a man a fish, he'll eat for a day. Teach a man to fish, he'll eat for a lifetime"

Comment: Ok, so f_c is 1/2πRC, but R and C are not given in the data sheet. This means that this question has no answer...

Comment: See section 45.7 (page 1403 to 1409) for the ADC characteristics with the information you need. kevin

Comment: I've looked there carefully. There is no stat that speaks of bandwidth - are you referring to voltage ripple?

Comment: No.  I was thinking of the calculation on page 1408.  But I agree that they leave a lot undefined or hidden as magic numbers in the equations.  Normally in a design you wouldn't rely on the ADC characteristics to define the BW.  At minimum I would put a capacitor to ground at the input to the ADC and a series resistor to give a first order low pass filter which gives you the bandwidth of the ADC.  The capacitor should be significantly larger than the sampling cap in the ADC, a fee hundred pF for example.